# Change/Rename Cell content after Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Thanks in Advance,

I'm collecting Data from Google Forms into a spreadsheet and filtering the data by using a query.
one of the form inputs, has a long description because its a question.
I'm trying to change/rename it after the Query much like you can set a new value to an object key in `JS`

is it possible in sheets,
cheers

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UJgspDiiC1F9eDdzyGJ2Wv-HcZ20R0D-Au4G3-CZqqw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Hey player here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UJgspDiiC1F9eDdzyGJ2Wv-HcZ20R0D-Au4G3-CZqqw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=QUERY(A1:C5,"Select 'Online',B,C label 'Online' 'Where Did the leads come from'",1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you man Appreciate that exactly what I was looking for cheers